# Regarding Journey Buider's implementation of sending emails and SMS

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, sms

I have one question regarding Journey Buider.
Is it possible to coexist SMS and email sending in one journey?

We are currently creating a journey that uses branching to send SMS to data that does not have an email address.
When I send the message, the email is delivered, but the SMS is not sent.
(Journey screen shows success.)

Comment: Yes, it's possible in multi-steps journeys. Regarding your problem, you need to give more details: SMS content, Journey's configuration, data extension values,..